# Is there a way to stagger React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to avoid using conditional statements with React Hooks, but I've reached a point where I may need some advanced techniques. I have here 3 hooks that depend on each other. Each hook returns a tuple `[bool, object]` that the next hook requires to execute.

Internally, each hook is an asynchronous operation and I don't have access to modify them.

```
const [loadingA, resultA] = useHook1(); 
const [loadingB, resultB] = useHook2(resultA.prop1); // Error!
const [loadingC, resultC] = useHook3(resultB.prop2); // Error!

if (loadingA || loadingB || loadingC) {
   return <span>loading...</span>;
}


// All results are required for this component.

return <MyComponent x={resultA.x} y={resultB.y} z={resultC.z} />;
```

The above breaks because `useHook2` and `useHook3` require the arguments to be defined. Unfortunately, I can't use a condition like this:

```
// this is not allowed

if (!loadingA) {
   const [loadingB, resultB] = useHook2(resultA.prop1);
}
```

Does anyone have any tips on how to stagger hooks such that they execute based on the result of a previous asynchronous hook?

Comment: Create another hook that lets you process multiple async actions at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Return some default value in **hook2** and **hook3** if the parameter is **undefined**. If you can't modify **hook2** or **hook3** directly, you can always wrap them in another hook (useHook2Wrapper, useHook3Wrapper) and do the **undefined** value validation.

```
const [loadingA, resultA] = useHook1(); 
const [loadingB, resultB] = useHook2(resultA && resultA.prop1);
const [loadingC, resultC] = useHook3(resultB && resultB.prop2);
```

```
const useHook2 = (someProp) => {
  if (!someProp) {
    return [false, undefined];
  }

  // rest of the hook logic
}
```